# vb not showing elements inside wizard

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I have a wizard that has two textboxes , when I click a button i want to take the textboxes Text but the problem is i cant find it, it says something like its not declared? how do i access it? by the way its a start navigation template. thanks

I already tried using

```
    Dim s As String
    Dim TextBoxOne As TextBox

    TextBoxOne = Wizard2.ActiveStep.TemplateControl.FindControl("TextBox1")
    s = TextBoxOne.Text
```

but it gives me a null reference exception??

Comment: the wizard are opened within this form?

Comment: @ziadmansour its a website and yes

Comment: please be more specific of what you are working on

Comment: @ziadmansour its a web form that has a wizard and the first step is a registration step so when i want to store the data provided I cant seem to access it like s = TextBox1.Text, there must be a way to do it but I'm totally lost here

Comment: try to use it as an object of the class type desired, then access it

Comment: example: form1 f = new form1(); s = f.TextBoxOne.Text